# Ractive.js instances binding with Array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, ractivejs

I'm using Ractive.js for reactive DOM-update on two pages. So, I have two different Ractive instances.

```
var ractiveDropdown = new Ractive({
    el: '#el',
    template: '#template',

    data: {
        products: []
        ...
}

 var ractiveOrder = new Ractive({
            el: '#el2',
            template: '#template2',
            data: ractiveDropdown,
            adapt: [ 'Ractive' ]
 });
```

Data here is an array containing some JSONs like this:

```
var products = [{id: 0, count:5, price:100}, ...]
```

When I setting this data like so:

```
update: function (products) {
            ractiveDropdown.set({products: products});
        }
```

, I get **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**.

It only happens with array-data, not with scalar values or even Objects.

Also this doesn't appear when I'm trying to iterate through **products** array with *forEach* and push every element to **products** data property.

What possibly goes wrong here? What should I do to avoid this SO-problem?

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the issue (e.g. in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/va6jU/))?

Comment: @RichHarris solved. It turned out that my problem appears on Ractive v0.7.3, but it perfectly works on v.0.8.0. Your link helped a lot, btw :)